# When choosing elements from the set, can you take the same element for two variables?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$

Statement: $\forall x  \in A$, $\exists y \in A$ such that $x + y$ is an even integer.

If I want to prove that this statement is correct, can $x$ and $y$ refer to the same value in set $A$ ?

Comment: Yes they can. Nowhere in the statement it is specified that $y$ cannot equal $x$. If it was specified that $y\ne x$, then the statement would be false as there does not exist a $y\in A$ such that $2+y$ is even and $y\ne 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two variables can refer to the same object.